# System of equations between with sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I came across this problem, and I've been thinking about it for a long time now, but I just can't wrap my head around it. How do you approach this:

Solve the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}A\cup X = X \cap B\\B \cup X = X \cap C \end{cases}, A\subseteq B \subseteq C$$

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$A\cup X=X\cap B\subseteq X\implies A\subseteq X.$$
Similarly $B\subseteq X$. The first line changes to $X=X\cap B$, hence $X\subseteq B$, by double inclusion $X=B$.

Comment: Why $X \cap B \subseteq X$  in the first line?

Comment: @SofiaB.Lopez because $X\cap B$ can't contain more element than $X$

Answer (score 1):

In both of the equations, $$RHS\subset X\subset LHS$$
Therefore, all four expressions are equal to $X$ and hence, 
$$X\cap B=X\cup B=X$$
$$\implies X=B$$